# Proxing Python class to Objective-C

Tags: python, objective-c, pyobjc

I try to proxy existing Python class to Objective-C. I started from simple sample of Python class:

**Test.py**

```
class Test:
    def __init__(self):
        self.text = ""

    def addText(self, _text):
        self.text = self.text + _text

    def addSomeText(self):
        self.addText("SomeText")
```

Then I wrote Objective-C class for it.

**ITest.h**

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>


@interface ITest : NSObject

- (void) addText: (NSString *)text;
- (void) addSomeText;

+ newTest;

@property (nonatomic, assign, getter = _text) NSString *text;

@end
```

**ITest.m**

```
#import "ITest.h"

#define ABSTRACT { return nil; }
#define ABSTRACT_VOID { }


@implementation ITest
@dynamic text;

- (void) addText: (NSString *)text ABSTRACT_VOID;
- (void) addSomeText ABSTRACT_VOID;

+ newTest {
    return [[NSClassFromString(@"TestProxy") new] autorelease];
}

@end
```

My proxy class (following some articles about PyObjC I subclassing Objective-C class and subclassing original class to access its instance variables):

**TestProxy.py**

```
import Foundation
import objc

from Test import Test

ITest = objc.lookUpClass("ITest")

class TestProxy (ITest, Test):
    # getters/setters
    def setText_(self, _text):
        self.text = _text

    def _text(self):
        return self.text

    # methods
    def addText_(self, text):
        Test.addText(self, text)

    def addSomeText(self):
        Test.addSomeText(self)
```

Now, if I do

`ITest *test = [ITest newTest];`

I always get `nil` with no warnings or errors in the debug console.

If I remove all imports and references to original `Test` class, I'll get working object. I noticed, that `nil` will be returned exactly as soon as I add `from Test import Test`.

I think this happens because PyObjC trying to bridge the `Test` class and fails because its methods do not conform bridge naming rules.

Is there a way to say PyObjC not to do so? Or, maybe, all stuff I did is wrong and there is a better way to translate existing Python stuff to Objective-C?

Comment: You are doing a few strange things that I would expect to cause problems later, but as far as creating an instance of `ITest`, your code runs successfully for me. I assume you're checking the value immediately after `ITest *test = [ITest newTest];`? I.e., `NSLog(@"%@", test);` -- this prints `<TestProxy: 0x4290ca0>` when I do so on the very next line.

Comment: @josh-caswell Well, I'm pretty new to PyObjC and it isn't well documented. How do you incorporate python stuff? I created a framework target with all files mentioned above which depends on Python.framework and added .m file with function TestProxy_Init — ...skip PYTHONPATH stuff... Py_Initialize(); PyImport_ImportModule("TestProxy");. In my main app I call TestProxy_Init and creating ITest.

Comment: Your experience is more Python than Obj-C, I take it? The docs for PyObjC are definitely not comprehensive. The important thing for figuring this problem out is: where are you checking the value of `test`? Could you post the code of this `TestProxy_Init` function, and the code that calls it?

Comment: Yes, I experienced with Python much more, I just starting to diving into Obective-C and Xcode, and, to my shame, it was a problem: while checking out for additional code to post I've noticed that Test.py file was not copied in framework's Resources by Xcode (I used [NSBundle bundleWithIdentifier:] and setenv for "PYTHONPATH" with [thisBundle resourcePath] in TestProxy_Init function). Apparently I forgot to add it in build settings. I added it and all working good. Anyway, thanks for help, the main thing I've learn is that I complicate things here too much.

Comment: The PyObjC bridge can be a troublesome beast; it's a really wonderful thing, but because what it does is so difficult, there are rough edges. Glad you solved it; best of luck, and if you have more questions, don't hesitate to ask here on SO!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just want to make sure that you wrote newText method without return type intentionally..
objective-c methods have its return type most likely, and if you don't want to a specific type to be return use keyword "id".